# i3 rendering strings incorrectly when used with Font Awesome 5 due to ligatures

Tags: linux, fonts, linux-mint, i3-window-manager

The following screenshot shows how my desktop is rendered when i3 is configured with `font pango:Noto Sans 9`. At the top, notice that the window name is correctly rendered as `2022-08-05-setup-laptop-2021`. The downside when using `Noto Sans` font is that some custom icons are not rendered correctly (specifically, the icon next to the string `Down` at the bottom bar).

[image]

In an attempt to render richer icons, I have configured `i3` to use `font pango:Font Awesome 5 Free Solid 9` instead of `Noto Sans`. The following screenshot shows that, this time, the custom icon next to the string `Down` at the bottom bar is indeed correctly rendered.

But here is the catch: some strings that were being correctly rendered at the first screenshot, now look weird. Take, for instance, the string `laptop` at the top bar of the first screenshot. It was incorrectly replaced by an icon of laptop.

[image]

In the past I've successfully set up something similar properly, and I don't remember having any kind of issues like this one.

From what I can tell, `Font Awesome` should only render UTF8 symbols. It shouldn't replace substrings with icons. I wasn't even aware that fonts were able to replace whole substrings from a text (perhaps it's a Pango thing?!).

And I can't find any documentation from Pango or Font Awesome explaining why this could be happening and how to avoid it.

Given the above, my question is: how can I use `Font Awesome` with `i3` in a way that it does not convert substrings to icons? (i.e. I don't want the `laptop` substring, at the window name at the top bar of the second screenshot, to be replaced by a laptop icon).

Comment: `I wasn't even aware that fonts were able to replace whole substrings from a text` It's a font feature called "ligature". Like the way ae can be written æ.

Comment: @Thomas thank you very much for your insightful comment. Doing a bit of research, I got to find out that they have indeed implemented ligatures since Font Awesome version 5 (https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/desktop/reference-icons/use-ligatures), which is exactly the version I'm having problem with. Also, I saw a comment inside a Github issue (https://github.com/vhakulinen/gnvim/issues/148#issuecomment-975778881) saying that it might be impossible to disable ligatures with pango, so I might have to resort to reverting to Font Awesome 4 perhaps.